# × Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, spotify

I have an if statement that checks if an access token is defined, if so it runs these 2 fetch requests.
I have the first fetch request returning the information i want.
I simply wanted to log the output of a separate fetch request that is taking info from a separate endpoint...
My local server keeps returning the error mentioned above and i cant quite figure out why

Here is the code i am trying to run.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    let accessToken = queryString.parse(window.location.search).access_token;
    
    if (accessToken != undefined) {
      //working fetch request..
      fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          serverData: {
            user: {
              name: data.display_name,
              profileLink: data.external_urls.spotify,
              images: data.images
            }
          }
        });
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.state.serverData);
      })

      // breaks on this line
      fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing', {
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      // here i am simply trying to log the returned data
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
    }
  }
```

now i do believe this is probably a small syntax error but i cant seem to knock it, would really appreciate any incite into this bug, thanks!

Comment: Just to also note this is a pretty tricky request to go and test yourselves as it is using the spotify API and requires O-Auth in order to allow access, my bad for forgetting to mention that. Unless ye have your own spotify O-Auth backend working (somehow haha) i wouldnt bother trying to run the fetch requests raw from an IDE

Comment: Have you verified that the response contains a valid JSON payload? That error message can be pretty common when calling `response.json()` on a response object with an empty payload.

Comment: After analyzing the response further in the console it does look like the payload is the issue, cheers for that tip. I must look into further!

Answer (score 0):

Add `.catch(error => console.log(error))` blocks after your `.then()` blocks, to see the error in the console and let me know what the error is. You'll get a lot more information like this.